# Filter Apollo connection with nested variables

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'd like to specify a nested argument as the `filter` for my `@connection` directive. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
input CommentsInput {
  postId: String!
  cursors: CommentsCursorInput
}

query getComments($input: CommentInput) {
    getComments(input: $input)
    @connection(key: "comments", filter: ["input.postId"]) {
        comments {
            id
            commentBody
            createdDate
            liked
            likeCount
        }
    }
}
```

`postId` is passed in `input`. This is a contrived example and I know I can structure this differently, but my main questions is can I use nested arguments as a filter, or can I only use top-level arguments in that `filter` array? I didn't see any discussion of this in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/pagination.html#connection-directive).